# Magento error "Cannot apply the coupon code."

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I'm trying to apply a coupon code using a Shopping Cart Rule in Magento 1.4.1.1 but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm getting an "Cannot apply the coupon code." error.
And here is the exception from the exception.log file:

```
2013-10-03T17:47:21+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'coupon_code' in 'where clause'' in /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#3 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(706): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#5 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(707): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(620): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(590): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getData()
#8 /home1/interkid/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(264): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#9 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/local/BTS/Checkout/Model/Observer.php(22): Varien_Data_Collection->getItems()
#10 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1228): BTS_Checkout_Model_Observer->addShipping(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1209): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(BTS_Checkout_Model_Observer), 'addShipping', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#12 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/Mage.php(416): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_quote_sav...', Array)
#13 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(379): Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_sav...', Array)
#14 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote.php(188): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_beforeSave()
#15 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(304): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->_beforeSave()
#16 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php(368): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#17 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Checkout_CartController->couponPostAction()
#18 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('couponPost')
#19 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#20 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#21 /home1/interkid/public_html/app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#22 /home1/interkid/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#23 {main}
```

Can someone please give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: disable the BTS_Checkout module

Comment: Thank you Dave! It's the same solution I've reached myself after a couple of hours of trial and error. I've created a new magento install using the same database... the coupon worked... this ruled out the db problem. The I've started replacing all the core files with the one from the old install... the coupon worked... what was left were the custom theme I used and the modules. Finally I've got to the modules and after copying each one by one I found the culprit : the damn BTS_Checkout module!

Thanks again for your prompt reply! How did you know what the problem was? From the exception.log?